# $ajax is not working but $post is working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

This is my postrequest.js file

```
function ajaxPost(){

var $firstName = $('#firstName');
var $lastName = $('#lastName');
var $email = $('#email');

var customerData = {
firstName : $firstName.val();
lastName : $lastName.val();
email: $email.val();


};
$.ajax({

type: "POST",
contentType : "application/json",
url:"addCustomer",
dataType: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify(customerData),

success: function(response){

$('#postResultDiv').html(response);
console.log(response);
},
error: function(e){
alert('error'+e)
}



});

});

}

});

And this is my request.js file
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#customerForm').submit(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var url = $(this).attr('action');

$.post(url,{firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName,email:email}).done(function(response){
console.log('data');
$('#postResultDiv').html(response);


});



});


});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset= UTF-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src=" /postrequest.js"></script>

    <title>Form Submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1> Customer Registration</h1>
<div class="container">


        <form class="form-inline"  th:action="@{/addCustomer}" th:object ="${customerDTO}" id="customerForm" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName" style="margin-right:5px">FirstName:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}"  placeholder="Enter FirstName"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastName" style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:5px">LastName:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}" placeholder="Enter LastName"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:5px">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Enter email"/>
            </div>

            <button type="submit"  id ="submitCustomer" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:5px">Submit</button>
        </form>
</div>

    <div class="col-sm-7" id="postResultDiv">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the controller method.

@RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)

```
public String submitCustomer(  @ModelAttribute CustomerDTO customerDTO, Model model) {

    customerService.createCustomer(customerDTO);

    List<CustomerDTO> customerDTOS = customerService.getAllCustomers();

    model.addAttribute("customerDTOS", customerDTOS);
    return "customerList";

}
```

Here I want to input the customer table under the form in my web page. The $.post method is working. but $.ajax method in postrequest.js file is not working. please tell me what is the wrong with $.ajax method in postrequest.js file.

Comment: What does console/network tab says in browser?

Comment: There is no output in console

Comment: response doesn't come in console

Comment: And the network tab?

Comment: it shows status=200 method=post

Comment: Try this: url:'@Url.Action("addCustomer","YourControllerName")'   Note: @Url.Action is between the single quotes.

Comment: Could you share your $post method too, please?